# A program that will let the user input a string and then output each letter on a new line

Tags: input, char, while-loop, println

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program3_5
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = new String();
        System.out.println("Please enter a string: ");
        input=scan.next();
        int length;
        length = input.length;
        input.substring();
        System.out.println(charAt(0));
        while (length)
            {
                System.out.println(charAt(0 + 1));
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error stating that it "cannot find symbol - variable length"
I have tried numerous things yet I am having trouble getting it to work. New to Java! Thanks in advance.

For example if the user were to input: ***Hello There***
The Output would print the letters on separate lines.

Comment: Seems like this should be tagged homework.

Answer (score 1):

[`String#length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) is a method, not a field, of `String`. You need to call the method. In Java, methods are called (or "invoked") using parentheses. So, change

```
length = input.length;
// to
length = input.length();
```

---

Anticipating the next compile error you see:

```
while (length)
```

won't compile in Java because `length` is an `int`, but the condition part of a `while` must be a boolean. I'm guessing you want to continue as long as the string is not empty, so change the `while` condition to be

```
while (length > 0)
```

---

Other problems you'll need to solve to get your code to compile:

- [`String#substring()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) requires integer arguments

Also, the code will compile with the `String input = new String();` but the assignment is completely unnecessary. In Java, you *almost never* need to `new` a string. Instead, use string literals.